# how to get requestscope variable in external javascript

Tags: javascript, spring

I have some problem regarding request scope variables in spring application. Problem is I have an Object "xyz" which was added to reference data map in SimpleFormController. Now I want to get this object(xyz) from java script. This is done in internal javascript as '${xyz}', but I need to get this from external javascript file. please any one help me out. I know external java script file not come under request scope, But is there any possible solution?

thanks in advance,

Comment: can the value of the variable be session scoped and 'managed'?  then you could expose it using a second request, accessible to the external javascript

Comment: @Chandrashekhar Goka : Can you ask the question in detail ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, declare the script variable at global level. Now that variable can have the scope to external scripts files also.